# Direct link to Google Voice (or other Google applications) to log in as a specific user

Tags: google, google-workspace, google-voice, authentication

I use multiple Google accounts for email, documents, and Voice. If I go to Google Voice, it will recognize whatever my most recent session is and use that. This is almost always my work session, so I then have to go to switch my account to my personal Google account.

Thankfully, Google allows you to use the Switch Account feature, so I no longer have to log off or use an Incognito window. However, it's still a pain to have to switch every time.

Is there a way to specify in the Google Voice URL that I want to use a specific account so that I don't have to switch once the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple gmail or apps accounts for chrome. SO that when you want to access a different account, you simply click the icon on the top left corner and choose the account.

You can set that particular account to open specific tabs...

For example, my analytics is tied to my old gmail (long before apps), so when I open that chrome account, it opens email, webmaster and analytics.

I have an account for my sons little league baseball. When I open that chrome account, it opens email, drive, calendar, the leagues site, the wordpress login page and the mail chimp account.

To create additional chrome accounts go to the Chrome Settings, the 3 lines in the top right corner. Make sure you are logged into chrome, choose settings, scroll down to users, create a new user, simply enter the username (email address) and password of that account. Once there customize the settings

Answer (score 0):

Not being in the US I don't have access to Google Voice, but on some Google services, you can specify the *domain* you're using in the URL:

- http://mail.google.com - your personal (non-apps) account
- http://mail.google.com/a/somedomain.com - your account at `somedomain.com`

an similarly:

- http://drive.google.com - personal
- http://drive.google.com/a/somedomain.com - account at `somedomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one for Gmail:

https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?continue=http://gmail.google.com/gmail&service=mail&Email=xxxxxx

replace XXXX with your full gmail email address. Example: joeblow@gmail.com

Comment: Hi, could you post an example link for Google Voice instead? The link you provided refers to Gmail instead.